# Unity detecta "multiples" Joysticks y evita la asignación para multijugador

Tags: unity

Trabajo en un proyecto con soporte de multijugador (2 jugadores), y configuré el Input.Manager de manera que los joysticks estuvieran bien asignados:
*joy1_saltar, joy2_saltar*, etc... Todo perfectamente configurado por ese lado, sin embargo me topo con el siguiente problema:

Resulta que al hacer prueba no detectaba ni el joystick del primer jugador pero al realizar un pequeño código para obtener los joysticks conectados al computador me tope que supuestamente hay otros dispositivos conectados lo que evita que el mando de PS4 o Xbox sea reconocido como el joystick número 1 para que sea detectado por el **Input.Manager**.

Utilicé este pequeño código para obtener los nombres:

```
    string[] joys = Input.GetJoystickNames();
    for(int i = 0; i < joys.Length; i++){
        Debug.Log(joys[i]);
    }
```

Y lo que me da como resultado en la consola es lo siguiente: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver supuestamente existenotros dispositivos conectados que evitan que el mando del XBOX sea reconocido como el primer joystick y de está manera pueda funcionar correctamente con el Input.Manager...

**EDITADO:**
Confirmado que son "dispositivos" que Unity detecta como Joysticks, ya que al renombrar en el Input.Manager con el número enlistado de joystick donde se encuentra el mando de XBOX (como pueden ver en la imagen) Unity lo reconoce en el modo Test al darle Play al Juego, ejemplo **"joystick 4 button 0"**

Comment: para que plataforma estás desarollando????

Comment: para Windows, también esta dirigido a Android, pero estoy trabajando principalmente para Windows y el Proyecto está configurado para plataforma de escritorio

Comment: Intentaste ponerle alguno de los controllers simples que ya trae?

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con ello?, mi problema no radica en el Input.Manager amigo, básicamente Unity detecta otros dispositivos definiendolos como "joysticks" y eso evita que el mando de la XBOX sea reconocido por Unity como **joystick 1**

Comment: A que si **usaste** los "controllers" que traía ya en las librerías listos para agregar. Cuando programaba en unity3D con eso bastaba para poder usar el control de x-box en la pc.

Comment: Nop, ya que trato de que el juego tenga soporte para diferentes mandos incluyendo PS4, y utilizar la libreria me limitaria a usar solo joystick de xbox, aun asi yo quiero saber el porque unity detecta "varios" joysticks, ya que ni siquiera lo son, vamos, que en la imagen se ve que el "segundo joystick" ni siquiera tiene nombre.

Comment: Ok, deberías de intentarlo antes de preguntar, te pemite usar teclado, mouse y control de XBox al mismo tiempo

Comment: Si pero eso no funciona para multijugador.
Pero vi algo, resulta que reinicie Unity y solo me detecto el Mando de Xbox, pero para estar seguro reinicie Unity de nuevo y nuevamente me aparecieron esos dichosos "joysticks", esto ultimo lo realice varias veces y en unas ocasiones me aparecian esos dispositivos supuestamente conectados y en otras solo aparecia que el mando estaba conectado.

Comment: deberías de compartir la configuración de tus hotkeys

Comment: Por hotkeys a que te refieres?, a la configuración del **Input.Manager**? o a que? o:

Comment: sí, así es amigo

Comment: Debes configurar el inputManager, ya que si no usatste los controllers por default unity creer'a que el teclado es un joy, al igual que el mause...